# Как исправить подсчет слов на C++?

Tags: c++, отладка

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    char s[250];
    int count = 0;
    cin >> s;
    for(int i(0);i < strlen(s);i++){
        if (s[i] == ' '){
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << count+1 << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Почему-то не считает количество слов. Всегда 0.Подскажите, что исправить?

Comment: У вас `cin >> s` только до первого пробела копирует введенную строку в `s`.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, а как сделать для много строк? Циклом while?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Причина в том, что `cin >> s;` копирует введенную строку в `s` только до первого пробела, соответственно дальше уже пробелы не находятся.

Для ввода строки с пробелами можно воспользоваться функцией `std::getline`, и принимать введенную строку сразу в `std::string`. Тогда не придется опасаться переполнения буфера `s[250]`:

```
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);
```

Для обхода строки можно использовать `range` версию цикла:

```
for (auto c : s)
    if (c == ' ')
        count++;
```

Но ещё проще воспользоваться стандартной функцией [std::count](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/). Итоговый вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    size_t count = std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), ' ');
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
}
```

[Ссылка](https://repl.it/Cmjy/3) на действующий код.